# SQL Remove whitespace (duplicates)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a telephone database with around 300k records,

what I am wanting to do is remove the whitespace as follows:-

```
update SMSTelephone set
Telephone = replace(Telephone, ' ', '')
```

The problem is when I do this I get the following error:-

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SMSTelephone'. Cannot insert duplicate key in     object 'dbo.SMSTelephone'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I'm guessing the reason for this is that I could have a record like this:

1. 077 7777 7777
2. 07777777777

so removing the whitespace is going to fail as these two records would be duplicated.

Is there anyway I can still execute this command whilst not updating any records that would cause duplication?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I guess the `Telephone` column is your primary key? If so then I assume you don't want any duplicates anyway, so what should happen when they occur? Do you keep one and merge the other rows somehow? You might also want to consider adding a `CHECK` constraint to the field to ensure it only holds digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update ST set
  Telephone = replace(st.Telephone, ' ', '')
from SMSTelephone st
cross apply (select count(*) as cnt
             from SMSTelephone sti
             where replace(st.Telephone, ' ', '')=replace(sti.Telephone, ' ', '')) i
where i.cnt=1
```

To update one of them:

```
WITH CTE (Telephone,DuplicateCount)
AS
(
  SELECT Telephone,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY replace(Telephone, ' ', '') ORDER BY len(Telephone)) AS DuplicateCount
  FROM SMSTelephone
)
update CTE
set Telephone = replace(Telephone, ' ', '')
WHERE DuplicateCount = 1
```

To delete all but one:

```
WITH CTE (Telephone,DuplicateCount)
AS
(
  SELECT Telephone,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY replace(Telephone, ' ', '') ORDER BY len(Telephone)) AS DuplicateCount
  FROM SMSTelephone
)
delete from CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
```

Fiddle for update (similar is for delete)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e117/2/0

Comment: I tried this, and nothing updated. I just got `(0 row(s) affected)`

Comment: That works! However if you have two numbers like this: `07 77777777` and `07 77 77 77 77` this would fail as it would try to change both of them and I would get the duplicated field again.

Comment: I just tried with those two exact numbers, and I get `(0 row(s) affected)`

Comment: which is the case .. it will not update either. It will only update if there is only one version of the telephone available. It is what you asked. Why don't you just delete duplicates, and then make the update which is easier ..

Comment: Is is possible to trim one of them if both numbers are like: `07 77777777` and `07 77 77 77 77` ? or even remove the duplicate one with the space as that one would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

For that column to be a valid PK, the input data should really have been sanitised (DBA lecture over).

For a single column table, you'd typically create a mirror table for the clean data:

```
CREATE TABLE SMSTelephoneBak
( Telephone VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Insert the clean data into it:

```
INSERT into SMSTelephoneBak
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(telephone,' ','') FROM dbo.SMSTelephone;
```

Clear down the source table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.SMSTelephone;
```

Insert the cleansed data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SMSTelephone 
        ( Telephone )
SELECT Telephone FROM dbo.SMSTelephoneBak;
```

And finally, remove the temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.SMSTelephonebak;
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach as long as the duplicates are truly duplicates.  For instance, if you look at two records where one has phone number of 777 7777 and the other has 7777777, do the rest of the columns in these records all match or do they differ in some way.  If the rest of the columns differ then more work will be required.  If there are other columns and they match then you'd need to add that to the select distinct statement with some aggregate function like avg or max.

Comment: Yes, the solution I've outlined is the simple (single column) scenario described in the question. Aggregating data from other columns is a whole different topic...

Comment: Glad we agree on the data sanitisation aspect of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing this because the data has been entered either manually or by an application that has not sanitised input then checked for existing records.

A solution, rather convoluted though, is to add a WHERE clause that searches for anything that matches the cleaned up strings and then excludes it.

Comment: Fair point.. this sort of problem doesn't lend itself to clean solutions in my experience. The use of intermediate tables comes to mind.